# For each word in a string column in pandas dataframe find 5 surrounding words before and after and insert the new columns in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on text analytics. I am stuck with one problem. I need a solution for that.

I am trying to find surrounding words (5 or more) for each word in a string column in a pandas dataframe. Dummy dataframe shown in a screenshot. I have id column and I have text column. I am trying to create a new dataframe which has four columns ( id column, before, Word, After) as shown in the second screenshot(result dataframe) attached.

For example

dummy dataframe

[image]

result dataframe

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] . Your question should be self-contained, we should not have to go through links to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: please help, I have amended my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought about using `df.Text.extractall(...)`,
with 3 capturing groups (*Before*, *Word* and *After*), but the downside
was that e.g. the *After* group in one match could consume the content
that in the next match could be either the *Word* or at least the *Before*
group.

So I decided to do it other way:

- Apply to each row a function, returning "partial" result for this row.
- Gather results in a list of DataFrames.
- Concatenate them.

## Setup

**Source DataFrame:**

```
   ID   Text
0  ID1  The Company sells its products worldwide through its wide network of
1  ID2  Provides one of most often used search engines for HTTP sites
2  ID3  The most known of its products is the greatest airliner of the world
3  ID4  Xyz nothing
```

Note that I added a "no match" row (*ID4*).

**Words to match:**

```
words = ['products', 'most', 'for']
```

**No of words before / after:**

```
wNo = 3
```

In your code change it to whatever number you want.

## The solution

The function finding matches in the current row:

```
def find(row, wanted, wNo):
    wList = re.split(r'\W+', row.Text)
    wListLC = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), wList))
    res = []
    for wd in wanted:  # Check each "wanted" word
        for indW in [ i for i, x in enumerate(wListLC) if x == wd ]:
            # For each index of "wd" in "wList"
            wdBef = ''
            if indW > 0:
                indBefBeg = indW - wNo if indW >= wNo else 0
                wdBef = ' '.join(wList[indBefBeg : indW])
            indAftBeg = indW + 1
            indAftEnd = indAftBeg + wNo
            wdAft = ' '.join(wList[indAftBeg : indAftEnd])
            res.append([row.ID, wdBef, wd, wdAft])
    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['ID', 'Before', 'Word', 'After'])
```

Parameters are:

- *row* - the source row,
- *wanted* - the list of "wanted" words (lower case),
- *wNo* - number of words before / after the wanted word.

For each match found, the result contains a row with:

- *ID* - from the current row,
- *Before*, *Word*, *After* - respective parts of the current match.

Of course, the actual number of words in *Before* / *After* group can be
smaller, if there is no enough such words in the current row.

Note that this function splits the source row into **two** lists:

- *wList* - "original" words, to return later,
- *wListLC* - words converted to lower case, to match (remember that the
  "wanted" list should also be in lower case).

The result is a "partial" DataFrame (for this row, if no match then empty),
to be later concatenated with other partial results.

And now, how to use this function: To gather partial results, as a list
of DataFrames run:

```
tbl = df.apply(find, axis=1, wanted=words, wNo=wNo).tolist()
```

And to generate the final result, run:

```
pd.concat(tbl, ignore_index=True)
```

For my source data, the result is:

```
    ID               Before      Word                  After
0  ID1    Company sells its  products  worldwide through its
1  ID2      Provides one of      most      often used search
2  ID2  used search engines       for             HTTP sites
3  ID3         known of its  products        is the greatest
4  ID3                  The      most           known of its
```

Note that *Before* / *After* group can be an empty string, but only
in cases when the *Word* was either the first or the last in the current row.

## How to speed up this solution

Some increase in speed can be achieved with the following steps:

- Compile the regex in advance (`pat = re.compile(r'\W+')`) and use
  it in the function finding matches.
- Drop additional parameters and use global variables instead.

So the function can be:

```
def find2(row):
    wList = re.split(pat, row.Text)
    wListLC = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), wList))
    res = []
    for wd in words:  # Check each "wanted" word
        for indW in [ i for i, x in enumerate(wListLC) if x == wd ]:
            # For each index of "wd" in "wList"
            wdBef = ''
            if indW > 0:
                indBefBeg = indW - wNo if indW >= wNo else 0
                wdBef = ' '.join(wList[indBefBeg : indW])
            indAftBeg = indW + 1
            indAftEnd = indAftBeg + wNo
            wdAft = ' '.join(wList[indAftBeg : indAftEnd])
            res.append([row.ID, wdBef, wd, wdAft])
    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['ID', 'Before', 'Word', 'After'])
```

And to call it, run:

```
tbl = df.apply(find2, axis=1).tolist()
pd.concat(tbl, ignore_index=True)
```

I compared both variants using *%timeit* (for my test data) and
the average execution time dropped from *46* to *39* ms (*16* % shorter).
For larger dataset the difference should be more significant.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i tried it however it shows group of 3 words in a string before and after a matching word,                                                                    its not  showing me the words before and after for all the words given in the list.                                         
 Please confirm how can i perform separate str.extractall for each word from the list and then concetenate results as you have suggested above.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_bo again for the response. Getting an error while executing code                                                                    res = [ find(row, words, wNo) for _, row in df.iterrows() ] error - Series object doesn't have df attribute,         please help

Comment: You took this row from the **earlier** (yesterday) version. Now *find* function is called as *tbl = df.apply(find, axis=1, wanted=words, wNo=wNo).tolist()* and then, incstead all the rest there is *pd.concat(...)*.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, i tried to use the code for the dataframe which you have created and while executing the code                                                        tb1 = df.apply(find, axis=1, wanted=words, wNo=wNo).tolist()                                                                  i am getting the error ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 1          Kindly help to resolve the error.

Comment: I came across such an error for *Python 2.7*.
So I suppose, you are using some "outdated" version of *Python* or *Pandas*. I use *Python 3.7.0* and *Pandas 0.24.0*.

Comment: @ Valdi_Bo Your code " res = [ find(row, words, wNo) for _, row in df.iterrows() ]  " worked for me and its amazing however the results are appearing in a list, how can i convert it to a pandas dataframe in an excel format with four columns as shown in the screenshot result dataframe with four columns ( id, before, word, after)

Comment: You still try to execute the code from **previous** version. Delete it and copy the **current** version on code.